# Location of default directories list stored for the 'origen new' command

Tags: origen-sdk

Where is the default directories list stored for the 'origen new' command? I would like to make a PR to add the 'vendor' directory as a default directory for the 'origen new' command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defined here:
https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_app_generators/blob/master/lib/origen_app_generators/application.rb#L25

Once you clone that plugin you can run the `origen app_gen:test` command from inside of it to test out your changes.
If you haven't already seen it, this guide will give some background on how the new application system works: http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/advanced/newapps

I've wondered about whether we should actually generate a .keep or .gitkeep file into empty directories like this so that they will stay around once the new app is checked in and cloned but nothing has been added to the dir yet.
Have a think about that for your PR.

Thanks!